# filter multidimensional array using key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given an array:

```
{
Key1:Data,
Key5:Data
   Array1[{
      Key4:Data,
      Key5:Data
          Array2[{
             Key1:Data,
             Key6:Data}
             ]
    Array3[{
       Key1:Data
       Key5:Data
      }]
   ]  
 }
```

and a list of keys to be deleted:

```
Key5
Array3
```

the desired result is:

```
{
Key1:Data,
   Array1[{
      Key4:Data
          Array2[{
             Key1:Data,
             Key6:Data}
             ]

    }]  
 }
```

if the keys to be deleted are changed to:

```
Array2
Key4
```

Then the desired result is:

```
{
Key1:Data,
Key5:Data
   Array1[{
      Key5:Data,
   Array3[{
      Key1:Data
      Key5:Data
      }]
   ]  
 }
```

Keys are not numeric, and I have tried array_diff,array_diff_ukey and array_diff_key to no avail - neither works with the nested arrays.  Thanks for looking at this!

Update:  I'm trying this code but it does not unset nested keys...

```
function searchArray(&$array1, $array2) {
    $ret=array();
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array1), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach($it as $k => $v) {
      if(is_array($k)){
        searchArray($k, $array2);}
     else{if(in_array($k,$array2)){
        unset($array1[$k]);}  //does not unset nested keys
     }
   }
}
```

Suggestions??

Comment: Did you try `unset` ?

Comment: @Vincent - I looked at unset but cannot seem to get the delete list to apply to the nested keys using just the key, i.e. I can use unset "Array1[key5]" but can't find a way unset "key5" without the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Walk through the array, and unset the elements.

```
array_walk_recursive(&$array, function($item, $key){
   if(in_array($key, $keys){ unset($array[$key]); }
});
```